# Why am I getting an error when trying to use transferArrayItem to move an array item from one Angular cdkDropList to another?

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I feel like I have to be missing something simple.  I'm trying to build a fairly simple application using Angular's DragDropModule.  I just want to transfer items from one cdkDropList to another.  I found something online that does something similar and got it functional.  But when I'm trying to adapt my own code, I keep getting an error that tells me currentArray.splice is not a function.

I've got the code over on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drag-drop-multitarget).

I have my code up top and the test code I found down below.  You'll note that the test code works as expected whereas mine throws the error.  The only thing I am seeing that is different is that I'm storing string values in my array and they are storing number values, but I have to be missing something else.  Anyone who can point me in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are pointed in the code below:

```html
 <div 
    id="scripture" 
    cdkDropList 
    [cdkDropListData]="words" <==== The square brackets around  [cdkDropListData] and the correct list name
    cdkDropListConnectedTo="wordbox"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="wordDrop($event)">
    <div 
      class="word-container unselect"    
      *ngFor="let wd of words">
      {{wd}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div 
    id='wordbox' <=== the correct id is wordbox, instead of wordbank
    cdkDropList 
    [cdkDropListData]="wordbank" <==== The square brackets around  [cdkDropListData]
    cdkDropListConnectedTo="scripture"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="wordDrop($event)">
    <div 
      class="word-piece unselect"
      *ngFor="let wd of wordbank" 
      cdkDrag
      cdkDragBoundary=".drop-targets"
      [cdkDragData]="wd">
      {{wd}}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am very disappointed in myself for missing the brackets.  I spent way more time than I care to admit trying to figure out why this wasn't working and comparing it against the code that was working.  "words" is actually not the correct list.  What I was originally trying to do was make each "word" a drop target, but I was failing to get that to work so I thought I would try using a secondary hidden list.  I might go back now and play with cdkdroplistgroup to see if my problem was really all because I forgot to include the square brackets.